# Has Sozzini's 'Brevis explicatio in primum Johannis caput' been translated into English?

Tags: gospel-of-john, resource-request, non-trinitarian, biblical-unitarian, logos

Lelio Sozzini (uncle of Socinus) wrote *Brevis explicatio in primum Johannis caput*, a commentary on the meaning of the Logos in John 1:1–15, and it was published in 1562. Sozzini held that the 'beginning' of John 1:1 was the same as 1 John 1:1, and both were about a new creation, not a Genesis creation.

His nephew (Socinus) then also wrote a longer *Brevis explicatio* which expanded on the original.

Have either of these works been translated into English?